# Error downloading file with especial characters in name with PHP

Tags: php, file, encoding, download

when I attempt to download a file which have a name with especial characters, (for example ó, í, ñ,...) I download a empty file. However if the file has a normal name it's download correctly. Here is my php code:

```
$archivo = $_GET['archivo'];
$ruta = "C:\ArchivosChirivoBPM\\" . $archivo;

$ext = pathinfo($archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: ' . $ext);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$archivo\"");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

readfile($ruta);
```

Comment: Looks like the special characters are not getting passed correctly to the $_GET variable. Did you check if  $ruta  doesn't return 404 error?

Comment: I resolve the problem. The solution is readfile(utf8_decode($ruta))